# script help, i am new to coding

Tags: javascript

hello i am new to coding , this is a google sheet app script problem that i have, so, i have 2 sheet and i want to sort in order both of them, sort different column , ive succeded in making the code work for both of them but my issue is that it will only work for 1 of them, seem like the function im creating only work for the 1st function ive enter, the second below dont work, but will work individualy, what im trying to do is to create 1 function that work for both of my sheet, anyone know ?

```
SHEET_NAME = "The Convenant { Member Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:J1187";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 5, ascending: true},  // 5 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 4, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
SHEET_NAME = "The Convenant ( War Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:I1086";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 2, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCO8I.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't duplicate twice the same function, for instance onEdit and multisortcolumns.
Try

```
function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
SHEET_NAME = "The Convenant { Member Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:J1187";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 5, ascending: true},  // 5 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 4, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');

SHEET_NAME = "The Convenant ( War Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:I1086";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 2, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

but may be yoy can test on which tab the onedit function is relative